# Python read lines from file by regex

Tags: python, regex, file, split, strip

I have a text file that I want to read into a list, in a certain format.

When I'm writing:

```
with open('chat_history.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

I'm getting:

```
27/08/15, 15:45 - text
continue text
continue text 2
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text
new text 2
new text 3
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text
```

I'd like to get:

```
27/08/15, 15:45 - text continue text continue text 2
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text new text 2 new text 3
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text
```

I want to split only when I'm in the format `\nDD/MM/YY, HH:MM -`
Unfortunately I'm not an expert at regular expressions. I tried:

```
with open('chat_history.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n'r'[\d\d/\d\d/\d\d - ]') for line in f]
```

Which gave the same result. In second thought, it makes sense why it doesn't work. Would love some help though.

Comment: Why not just test the current line and output a newline first if it matches?

Comment: How the file looks like?

Comment: The file is like `27/08/15, 15:45 - text continue text continue text 2`, but when I read lines I get `27/08/15, 15:45 - text\ncontinue text\ncontinue text 2`

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams there is no unwanted data. I'm using everything, I just want it to be in the correct format

Comment: @sheldonzy, have you tried `open('chat_history.txt', encoding='utf8', newline='')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, this might be *way over the top* and I'm sure there are other possibilities to accomplish the same. I'd like to present my solution here with `(?(DEFINE)...)` using the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/). First the code, then the explanation:

```
import regex as re

string = """
27/08/15, 15:45 - text
continue text
continue text 2
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text
new text 2
new text 3
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\ \d{2}:\d{2}) # the date format
    )
    ^                    # anchor, start of the line
    (?&date)             # the previously defined format
    (?:(?!^(?&date)).)+  # "not date" as long as possible
''', re.M | re.X | re.S)


entries = (m.group(0).replace('\n', ' ') for m in rx.finditer(string))
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
```

This yields:

```
27/08/15, 15:45 - text continue text continue text 2 
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text new text 2 new text 3 
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text
```

---

Basically this approach looks for date blocks, separated by text in between:

```
date
text1
text2
date
text3
date
text
```

... and puts them together like

```
date text1 text2
date text3
date text
```

The "date format" is defined in the date group, afterwards the structure is as follows

```
date "match as long as there's no date in the next line"
```

This is achieved via a negative lookahead. Afterwards all found newlines are replaced with a space (in the comprehension, that is).
Obviously, one could as well get the same result without the `regex` module and the `(?(DEFINE)` block but we'd have to repeat ourselves in the matching and lookahead.
In the end, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/A5mqoY/1/) for the expression.

Comment: Can't you just split by `\n(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\ \d{2}:\d{2})`

Comment: @SebastianProske: Yup.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('chat_history.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    l = [line.rstrip('\n').replace('\n', ' ') for line in f]

print(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses a simpler regex than Jan's.  The code using the regex is slightly more verbose though.

First, the input file:

```
$ cat -e chat_history.txt
27/08/15, 15:45 - text$
continue text$
continue text 2$
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text$
new text 2$
new text 3$
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text$
```

The code:

```
import re

date_time_regex = re.compile(r'^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2} - .*')

with open('chat_history.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    first_date = True
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')

        if date_time_regex.match(line):
            if not first_date:
                # Print a newline character before printing a date
                # if it is not the first date.
                print()
            else:
                first_date = False
        else:
            # Print a separator, without a newline character.
            print(' ', end='')

        # Print the original line, without a newline character.
        print(line, end='')

# Print the last newline character.
print()
```

Running the code (and showing no trailing spaces) :

```
$ python3 chat.py | cat -e
27/08/15, 15:45 - text continue text continue text 2$
27/08/15, 16:10 - new text new text 2 new text 3$
27/08/15, 19:55 - more text$
```